# Avoid changes in GET (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I get this url from a link (method GET) www.mypage.com/form.aspx?ID=1

I redirect the user to a form with all the info from the record Id = 1, but how can I avoid that the users "play" with the ID parameter and get the info from other records?

Sorry for not be clear...

My page has authorization methods, not problem there, but still an authorized user, shouldnt be allowed to see another record that not correspond to the Id in the URL (manipulating the ID  directly from the browser's url).

Comment: Best bet is to leverage sessions. It's baked-in to ASP.Net, and ensures that the session belongs to a particular user, and based on that user's permissions, he may or may not have access to a particular resource.

Answer (score 6):

### You Can't.

If the url does not require authentication or authorization, you should assume that anyone will be able to access it, and will manipulate the parameters. If you need to truly prevent access to other records, you'll have to set up authentication and authorization to only enable certain records for certain users, groups, or roles.

Answer (score 0):

In the form.cs file do some checking to see if the user has proper access to that form ID, if the user does not have, don't show the information.

Comment: I undestand that, but that cheking has to be in the DB privilegies?

Comment: That depends on what defines if the user has access to a particular record. If that is controlled in a database, then yes.